# Chrome extension background script "Cannot access contens of URL devtools..." error?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have a background script called events.js
I am occassionally getting this error

> Unchecked runtime.lastError: Cannot access contents of url
>   "devtools://devtools/bundled/devtools_app.html?remoteBase=https://chrome-devtools-frontend.appspot.com/serve_file/@ed9d447d30203dc5069e540f05079e493fc1c132/&dockSide=undocked".
>   Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.

It is apparently being generated not by events.js but by "_generated_background_page.html" but appearing in my background console log.

I suspect it is being caused by my call in events.js to:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(function(e) {
   // do stuff
}
```

It is driving me nuts. Can anyone please tell me what is going on?

Comment: A devtools window is like any other browser window so it may be reported in your webNavigation or some other listeners. But you can't access devtools window contents from your extension. Something inside the listener tried to access it and got blocked. All you need to do is something like `if (chrome.runtime.lastError) return` inside your listener.

Comment: Thanks, i've inserted that line of code to see if it helps with the errors. But I also realize that my listener is picking up on pushstate changes from other unrelated websites in other tabs (e.g youtube). This does not really make sense. How can i get my  extension to only focus on push state changes from my tab in question, or from a particular URL (via url matching or something similar?) ?

Comment: You can use url filtering, see the documentation, like this chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(fn, {url: [{hostEquals: 'www.google.com'}]}) but as for tab scoping you'll have to perform a check inside the listener, there's no way to specify a tabId filter.

Comment: Hi @wOxxOm i'd like to mark your "comment" as the answer as i believe my issue has been fixed, not sure how to though?

Comment: You can summarize it in your own answer with relevant excerpts from your real code .

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue happened to me today. One of those facepalm moments. I discovered as i had a breakpoint in my background script to check something before the content-script was executed in the handle message, that this background devtools tab became the active tab and tired to inject the script and not the intended tab from which I activated my extension.

Hence the error.

> Cannot access contents of url
> "devtools://devtools/bundled/devtools_app.html?remoteBase=https://chrome-devtools-frontend.appspot.com/serve_file/@7345a6d1bfcaff81162a957e9b7d52649fe2ac38/&dockSide=undocked".